# WordPress popular tags

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

Has anyone any ideea how to determine the 5 popular tags of the week on a wordpress blog? Popularity is determined on how many times was used a tags.

Anyone?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/most-popular-tags/

Comment: Yeah, I tried this before but I can't install it because of "Fatal error: Class 'WP_Widget' not found in /home/groupsjr/infrastructurist.com/test/wp-content/plugins/most-popular-tags/mostpopulartags.php on line 30"

Comment: What about this one? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-tag-list/  It might also be helpful to get to know your version of wordpress. You can also search for the following code "wp_tag_cloud" and reduce the standard value which is 45 tags to 5.

Comment: I have now something like this `wp_tag_cloud('smallest=12&largest=12&unit=px&number=5&orderby=count');` but I need the tags only from the last week :| and wp_tag_cloud does not have such argument.